# Webclient causing an invalid operation exception

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to download a simple xml file and save it to the users local profile. When trying to download (i don't think this has anything to do with the saving location but i'm not 100% sure) i get the following exception on the webclient.

System.InvalidOperationException

My code is as follows;

```
public void downloadProxy()  {
            string url = Properties.Settings.Default.url;
            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "/netsettings/proxies.xml");

        try
        {               
            WebClient GrabFile = new WebClient(); 
            GrabFile.DownloadFile(url, path);   
        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            if (webEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Are you behind a firewall?  If so, go through the proxy server.");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: did you tried printing the path or somthing? maybe the url is wrong?

Comment: lol, of course i have!

Comment: where's the exception actually happend? which line? and also get the inner exception please(print webex.ToString())

Comment: it does in fact look to be the path (not the url). the error was being produced when i added the enviroment.getfolder.. bit. I changed it to proxies.xml and it saved it to the debug project folder. I'm attempting to save this to the users local profile

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows operating system, use a backslash (not a slash) as folder separator:

```
\netsettings\proxies.xml
```